# How to find a missing bag that has been forwarded via a third airline?

Tags: luggage, europe, airlines, wizz-air, lost-luggage

I had a flight with Wizzair within Europe and my bag was missing. I made a property irregularity report at the airport for my bag to be delivered to my final destination, which was in another continent and I flew there with another airline on a separate ticket. After a few days, the third-party handling agent at the airport where I filed the report updated my Worldtracer lost report, saying they had found my bag and had forwarded it via a third airline to my final destination, including the flight numbers and airline name on which my bag would be flying to me.

It has now been 12 days and I have not received the bag. The third airline either refuses to talk to me since I am not their client, or says they will look into it. The airport third-party agent tells me to no longer contact them, as since they gave the bag to the third airline, it is no longer their problem. Wizzair, the airline I flew with, has no phone support and is unresponsive via forms. I received a vague response after around one week.

Is there anything I can do to get someone to chase what is happening with my bag, especially since, according to Worldtracer, the bag is supposed to be with the third airline already in my final city (I tried going to the local airport with no luck)? I also got no documents/proof or code from the third airline to confirm my bag was in fact forwarded to them. The third-party agent says the only confirmation available is the note on my Worldtracer report, written by the third-party agent themselves. Is there any document/third airline confirmation code I can demand from them?